# Reorder dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would still take advantage of the expertise and availability of this community.
Today my mind seems to be blocked, I would like to know if there is a better way to reorder these tags.

```
<h3>title</h3>
<div>a</div>
<div class="order">b</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<h3>title</h3>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div class="order">b</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<h3>title</h3>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div class="order">b</div>
<div>a</div>
```

In this way

```
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="order">b</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="order">b</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<h3>title</h3>
<div class="order">b</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
```

I have tried this way but it seems excessively verbose solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var h3=$('h3');
        h3.each(function(){
            var divs=$(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div class="group"></div>');
        });

     $('div.group').each(function(){
        var a=$('<div class="temp1">temp</div>').prependTo($(this))
        var divs=a.nextUntil('div.order').detach()
        divs.appendTo($(this))
      })

     $('div.group div').unwrap()    
     $('div.temp1').remove()
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('h3').each(function(){
  $(this).nextAll('.order').first().after($(this).nextUntil('.order'));
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NkWm9/)

Or as per my colleague's suggestion,

```
$('.order').each(function(){
 $(this).after( $(this).prevUntil("h3"));
})
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/NkWm9/2/)

Comment: @Devima You can accomplish your task based on my new edit too.